# How to change multiple entries in config files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ide

I notice in VS2013 that if I highlight text with a view to making a change, the same text is highlighted elsewhere in the file. However, I can't seem to find the option to reflect the change in multiple places when I start typing.

Is this feature just for information only or can I actually do multiple replacements by typing the change once?

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported out of the box.

But there is a nice plugin you can use to enable this, called [MultiEditing](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2beb9705-b568-45d1-8550-751e181e3aef).

H/T to [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SimultaneousEditingForVisualStudioWithTheFreeMultiEditExtension.aspx) :)

---

Also note that even in standard VS2013, you can edit multiple lines by "box-highlighting".
This is where you create a "box-selection" either by holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and dragging a box around the text, or by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ArrowKeys</kbd>. Then start typing and the same text will appear on multiple lines.

e.g. with the following text:

```
Some text to demonstrate
Some info to demonstrate
Some more to demonstrate
```

...if you <kbd>Alt</kbd>+drag a box-selection around all 3 occurrences of the word `to`, and then type `which`, it will look like this:

```
Some text which demonstrate
Some info which demonstrate
Some more which demonstrate
```

This also works with copy/paste - the pasted text gets applied to all lines within the box-selection.

*It's pretty hard for me to describe here, so try it yourself!*

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm familiar with the ALT block feature but unfortunately, the text blocks in question aren't always contiguous..